# C言語　ポインタ　領域確保

Tags: c

下記は自分のプログラムなのですがどうしても実行結果がうまくいきません。
for文かmallocのどちらかがおかしいと思うんですが分かりません。

**問題:**

> キーボードから空白類を含まない 32bytes 未満の文字列を 1 つ入力すると、その文字列の各文字を2つずつに増やした新しい文字列を入れる領域をmallocで確保し新しい文字列を入れ、表示した後メモリを解放して終了するプログラムを作成せよ。
>
> 例："abc" → "aabbcc"

**現状のプログラム**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(void){

  char *p,q[32];
  int i,k,j;

  printf("Input MOZI:");
  scanf("%s",q);

  i=strlen(q);

  p=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* i * 2);
  if(p == NULL){exit(1);}

   printf("%d\n",i);

  for(k=0;k<i;k++){
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
   *p=*q;
   *p++;
    }
  j=0;
  ++*q;

  }
  printf("%s\n",p);
  printf("%s\n",q);

  free(p);

}
```

Comment: オフトピックとしてこの質問へクローズ票を入れます。なぜなら質問者と回答者は対等な立場であり、質問者は「プログラムを作成せよ」などと命じる立場にはありません。

Comment: @ともや さん、スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問で、ともやさんが分からないと思ったポイントはどこでしょうか？　何か問題文のようなものとプログラムが書かれていますが、これはどういった関係にあるものでしょうか。もしこのプログラムがともやさんの書いたもので、それが上手く動かないのであれば、どういった状況でどのように上手くいかないのかの説明が欲しいです。質問文下の「編集」から質問文を自由に改善できますので、問題点が分かりやすくなるように質問文を推敲してみてください :)

Comment: ヒントです、文字列”ABC"を格納するのに必要な領域のサイズは何バイトでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri この引用文は別に回答者に命令しているのではなくて、参考にしている本か何かでこのような出題があり、それをそのまま記述しただけだと思いますよ。

Comment: C ではなく Java で書かれているコードですが、考え方の参考になるかもしれません。[Java exercises: Repeat every character twice in the original string](https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/string/java-string-exercise-82.php)

Comment: @ともや さん、「上手くいかない」にもたとえば「コンパイルエラーが出る」「実行時エラーが出る」「実行はできるのだけど挙動が想定と違う」などがあり、ともやさんのお手元でどうなっているか私たちには分かりません。どのようにお困りなのかも書いて頂けると回答しやすいです。エラーが出ているのであればそれをコピー＆ペーストしていただいたり、挙動が違うなら想定挙動と実際の挙動を書いていただいたりすると嬉しいです。

Comment: @kishikawa katsumi 編集履歴を見て頂ければ分かりますが、質問当初は「問題」のみが書かれていたのでそれに対するコメントかと思います。/ 指摘を受けてご本人からの追記がされたので、引用になっているのは私が見やすくなるよう編集しました。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。いきさつを理解しました。

Comment: うまくいかない、ではなく、入力例とそれに対する実際の出力、期待する出力を書くと良い質問になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

*p++と++*qをp++と++qに変えてみて下さい。
ポインタを進めたいのであって、中身を変えたいわけではありませんよね？
*を使うとポインタの指す中身が参照されます。
ちなみに厳密にいえば、*よりも++が優先されるはずなので、*p++は問題ありません。が、紛らわしいのでアスタリスクは外したほうがいいと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

ザッと見たところでは、以下の様な問題があります。
学習のために何処の何がと細かい指摘はしませんので、自分で調べてみてください。

- 取得する入力文字列を32bytes未満に収めるための対処をしていない
- 領域確保の際に文字列の終端を示すデータの長さを考慮していない(@akira ejiriさん指摘)
- 各文字をコピーする過程で元々のポインタそのものを書き換えている(のでその後の表示や領域解放が上手く行かない)
- コピー先文字列の終端を示すデータが書きこまれていない